# Why does $\sqrt{n} (\bar X - \mu)/S$ have approximately a $t$-distribution?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Suppose that the random variables $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are independent and identically distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Let $\bar X = (X_1 + \cdots + X_n)/n$ be the sample mean and $S = ((X_1 - \bar X)^2 + \cdots + (X_n - \bar X)^2)/(n-1)$ be the sample variance.

If the random variables $X_i$ are normally distributed, then $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)/\sigma$ is normally distributed and $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)/S$ has a $t$-distribution. Moreover, even if the random variables $X_i$ are not normally distributed, then $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)/\sigma$ is approximately normally distributed, according to the central limit theorem.

**Question:** In this case (where the random variables $X_i$ are not normally distributed), does the central limit theorem also imply that $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)/S$ has approximately a $t$-distribution?

---

This question arises in the context of constructing confidence intervals for the mean of a random variable, in the case where the variance is unknown.

The following passage appears in Ross's book Introduction to Probability and Statistics for Engineers and Scientists:

> Our derivations of the $100(1-\alpha)$ percent confidence intervals
>   for the population mean $\mu$ have assumed that the population
>   distribution is normal. However, even when this is not the case, if
>   the sample size is reasonably large then the intervals obtained will
>   still be approximate $100(1-\alpha)$ percent confidence intervals for
>   $\mu$. **This is true because, by the central limit theorem,
>   $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)/\sigma$ will have approximately a normal
>   distribution, and $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)/S$ will have approximately a
>   $t$-distribution.**

I'm trying to understand the final statement about $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)/S$ having approximately a $t$-distribution.

Comment: The central limit theorem states, under appropriate conditions, that $\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}-\mu)/S \overset{\mathcal{D}}{\rightarrow} N(0, 1)$. It has nothing to do with the $t$-distribution. For finite $n$, the exact distribution would be $t$-distributed if the $X_i$ are themselves normal. When the $X_i$ are not normal, anything goes in terms of the finite-sample properties.

Comment: @TomChen Thanks. I added a quote from a book I'm reading -- I don't see the justification for the final statement about $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)/S$ having approximately a $t$-distribution.

Comment: As the degrees of freedom tends to $\infty$, $S\to\sigma$ in probability and the $t$-distirbution approaches $N(0,1)$.

Comment: @eternalGoldenBraid Sorry, my comment came almost the same time as your edit, adding in the passage. Presumably, for finite $n$, $S$ does suffer from being variable in itself, and that should be accounted for. Heuristically, it would make sense to use a distribution with heavier tails to account for this additional variability. But, there is no reason to choose $t$ other than our familiarity with it.

Comment: @TomChen Hmm, it seems to me that the only reason $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)/S$ is approximately $t$-distributed is that it is approximately normally distributed. But this makes the statement in the book kind of silly. Seems like the book should just make the simpler statement that $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)/S$ is approximately normally distributed.

Comment: The argument goes that in most realistic cases, $S^2$ may sometimes be small by chance and so $\frac1S$ may be large making $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)/S$ also large in magnitude.  The $t$-distribution handles this issue exactly when the underlying population is normally distributed with its heavier tails and its variance above $1$, and can often be a better approximation than the normal distribution in other cases

Comment: "Approximately" just means approximately. The point here is that not knowing the variance parameter $\sigma^2$ has "some" effect. This effect can be precisely analyzed under "clean" and "clear" assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

According to the central limit theorem $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)/\sigma$ tends to standard normal distribution as $n$ tends to infinity. But by the same token, since $s$ tends to $\sigma$ a.s., the variable $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)/s$ tends to standard normal distribution as well. Since the $t$-distribution is a sequence of distributions and not the single distribution it's hard to define what we mean by "tends" to. If we mean it in the sense of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov distance or something along these lines, we then indeed can say that it approaches the $t$-distribution. But it's only the consequence of the fact that $t$-distribution approaches standard normal i.e. we could say the same thing for any other sequence of distributions converging to normal. It could happen that $t$-distribution is a better asymptotic approximation of $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu)/s$ than standard normal and it probably is in most cases. However, both can be used in the asymptotic case.

Answer (score 1):

In Ross's book, $\sqrt n (\overline{X} - \mu) / S$ has t distribution requires the nominator to be standard normal random variable (which under CLT satisfies). $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}$ needs to have chi-square distribution (which satisfies according to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104875/question-about-standard-deviation-and-central-limit-theorem) using Taylor expansion with second order). The final condition will be the independence between $\overline{X}$ and $S^2$ (which I don't know...)